# RecyclerView inside of NestedScrollView fires all onBindViewHolder at once

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to have scrollable screen with **RecyclerView** as one of its children, hierarchy would look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        .../>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                .../>

            <FrameLayout
                .../>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list_contacts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

            <FrameLayout
                .../>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that all the items of `RecyclerView` should be visible and be siblings of **ImageView**, **FrameLayout** etc.

In the current solution, there is one significant issue, **onBindViewHolder** is called for all items at once, but I want them to be bind when they appear on the screen, like in standard `RecyclerView`. I was doing some experiments with

```
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

but it failed after all.

I know one of the solutions is implementing **heterogeneous** recyclerView, but I would like to avoid it. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use `wrap_content` height if you don't want every view to bind up front. `wrap_content` height makes view recycling impossible.

Comment: Use `NonScrollRecyclerView` this makes simple to allocate the height of recyclerview at runtime. see this https://gist.github.com/abhi08singh/63a010b9ae7fddceec60a533d002e3fc

Comment: @BenP. ok, you wrote how NOT to implement it. Any advice how TO DO how to implement list of objects with rather complex header (or/and footer) placed before the first (or just after the last) element on the list?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it happens because in this case, recyclerview cant know the height of itself. 
Can you try:

```
layoutManager.isAutoMeasureEnabled=true
```